# Projection in Rest

Tags: java, web-services, rest

We are using projection in Rest Web-service. The Approach we are following is:

```
?projection= (attr1,attr2)&include=0.
```

where projection string contain name of all the variable which we want to include or exclude from output object. If the `include` is `0`  it means we want to exclude variable  and if include is `1` means we want to include variable which are given in `projection` string . Is this is correct and RESTful?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing bad in this approach when it comes to being RESTful or RESTless. On the contrary, field projection is very good practice which is widely utilized.

I don't know your scenario well, however the suggested solution seems to be too complicated. I'd rather remove `include` field and if `projection` is empty return the whole resource, otherwise return only the fields listed under `projection` query param.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but the scenario is we have 2 case's. 1st case is if user want to include only some field's out of all the field's(let's say 50 field's are there and he want only 2 field's) in that case he will give those 2 field's in projection string & give include=1. 2nd case is that user want to exclude 2 field's from output out off 50 field's in that scenario he won't have to pass rest of the 48 field's that he want, he can pass only those field's that he doesn't want & set include=0.

Comment: @DharmendraSingh Ok, then I'd rather change projection and include to exclude and include and support both inclusion and exclusion of fields at the same time. It looks much better than `include=(0|1)` and is much more readable.